# Is there an App Router version of Next.JS router.query?

Tags: next.js

I'm working on a project using the new Next.JS app router, and I'm struggling to retrieve the URL slug.

In the original Page Router (`next/router`), it was this easy

```
const router = useRouter();
const {slug} = router.query;
```

But I can't seem to find an equivalent `next/navigation`. Does anyone know?

Answer (score 1):

Just as I posted this I found the answer!

`import {useParams} from 'next/navigation'`

`const {slug} = useParams();`